# WIFI Connection with Live CD but not with installed OS

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, system-installation, livecd

I want to install Kali Linux but the problem is, when I start it from the Live CD my wireless adapter works, but when it's installed, my wireless adapter doesn't seems to work. Sorry, but I can't tell you more about that but maybe you could explain why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to

[Problem with touch pad in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220178/problem-with-touch-pad-in-linux)

You will need to know exact laptop model, wireless adapter and find out what is the required driver package, that you need to install to the OS.

Comment: Thank you but as i wrote, its working in live mode (on exact the same machine) and i have had installed kali several times before on that machine. so that couldnt be the issue, am i wrong? And i really dont see any relation to any touchpad on ubuntu?!?

Comment: its the same thing. Hardware is working from LiveCD and not after install. But really, without the hardware type there is no way how to find fitting drivers.

Comment: Sorry but i dont think so, the Driver is ath9k and its included in Kali Linux. i had installed the same ISO file several times before!!!

Answer (score 0):

I used to meet this problem when i install Ubuntu. Live CD is good, but real OS not.

The problem is in your blacklist, I guess your wireless adapter is "Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter".

If so, check your blacklist in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and commant `blacklist bcm43xx`

Comment: There is no entry named bcm43xx. There are just blacklist snd_pcsp
and blacklist pcspkr. i guess that means speaker, right?

Comment: I'm sorry but I use my Ubuntu blacklist. I check my Kali and I'm sure it's your mod problem. Try `lsmod` and find out what's wrong if you really wants to solve this problem.